# how i can create a stored procedure to insert in a table with an int auto_increment primary key?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I get error in the first line of create procedure
and this is the query that I've tried to create the stored procedure,

```
create procedure inhot(@nombre varchar(30), @p_categoria double, @p_direccion varchar(80), @p_descrip text, @p_tel varchar(15), @p_coords varchar(100))

as

begin

insert into hoteles(nombre, categoria, direccion, descrip, tel, coords) 

values(@p_nombre,@p_categoria,@p_direccion,@p_descrip,@p_tel,@p_coords)

end
```

Thanks